# Commenting in android layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I comment in xml file of android layout. I have seen [Comments in Android Layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484643/how-to-comments-in-layout-xml) - but I wanted to comment inside a parent.

When I try to do that I get an error in eclipse:

```
<Button android:text="Button" 
<!-- this is a comment -->
android:id="@+id/Discon" >
</Button>
```

From the background knowledge of xml, I came to know that we cannot add comments in attributes.
Is there any way of removing the id as attribute and specifying it as element?
Or is there any way to add comments inside attributes of elements?

Comment: specifying as element means ?

Comment: for example android:id is an attribute of Button element(xml style).. can I specify this attribute as a sub element inside the button element?

Comment: Just check the below link.Its describing the way we can comment
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484726/5858287

Answer (score 37):

you cannot embed a comment inside a tag.
between tags it's not a problem

```
<!-- 
     this is a comment 
 -->
<Button android:text="Button" 
   android:id="@+id/Discon" >
</Button>
```

if you want to temporary comment out an attribute (if that's what you want to know) you will have to move it ouside the tag and comment it there.

```
<Button android:text="Button" 
   android:id="@+id/Discon" 
  >
</Button>


==>

<!--   android:id="@+id/Discon" -->

<Button android:text="Button" 
  >
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is already specified in the post which I have shared. But I just wanted to know if there is an alternative to this..

Comment: this is the only way to add comment in a xml file

Answer (score 12):

Well not technically a comment, buy you can do

```
<Button comment="write whatever you want here" android:text="Button" ...
```

Or if you want to temporarily remove an attribute, remove the `android:` from the name.

Basically Android ignores everything without the `android:` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I use Android Studio, So i can tell u XML comment for A.S only.

Simply select the part of code you want to make it comment and

press (Ctrl+shift+?) It will add <1-- your Code -->, Here 1 is (Shift+1)( exclamation mark)

Remember one more thing , Here is one exception : Example

```
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/T_HomeworkMax1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF1E0101"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
            android:text="Max" />

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/T_HomeworkMin1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF1E0101"
            android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"

            android:text="Min" />
```

Here,You can not select just one or two lines from the code, You have to select full Node(TextView).

```
  <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/T_HomeworkMax1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF1E0101"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
            android:text="Max" />-->    

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/T_HomeworkMin1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FF1E0101"
            android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"

            android:text="Min" />
```

Now, First TextView is Comment.

Answer (score 1):

XML does not allow to comment between tags () which means you can't place comments to attributes as they'd be inside its tag.
You can't remove an attribute and place it outside its tag, because then it is no longer an attribute.

In short, what you're trying to do, in the way you try to do it, it simply cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below Code for comment in Android Studio:**

*Comment / uncomment a block of code.*
Ctrl + Shift + "/"

*Comment / uncomment a line of code.*
Ctrl + "/"

Comment: Please specify for which IDE this is. When I try this in notepad it does nothing.

Comment: @AndréKool It's for Android Studio.