# Can't use comments in XML files

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to add some comments in XML files using Android studio but it's breaking the code.

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Comment must be in its own tag, not in the middle of another tag.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Android, or Android Studio. XML comments go between XML elements ("tags"), not inside of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I'm trying to add some comments in XML files using Android studio but it's breaking the code.

You cannot add a comment inside a tag.

See [Commenting in android layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791556/commenting-in-android-layout-file) for more information.