# How to comment out line(s) in xml in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have the following piece of code in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file in which I want to comment out a single line (for quick testing purposes). By choosing the `AndroidStudio`-comment function I get the following:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/myicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"-->
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >
```

However, this creates a compilation error:

```
Error:Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Is there a simple way to comment out a (block of) line(s), or should I open an external text editor and copy-and-paste the original (block of) line(s) to that external text editor?

Answer (score 3):

You can comment out side the tag Like :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/myicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >

 <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"-->
```

Not inside the tag.

Comment: This seems to work. Not optimal, but better to copy all to another file. Wonder why AndroidStudio does not know about that...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in xml, if you want to add comments then you have must use xml syntax and syntax is use comments before starting or ending of tag

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put comments inside tags.  Please see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484726/267702) question.

Answer (score 0):

XML does not allow comments within a tag. You can only comment out elements as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it outside. See reference: [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-comments)